# Failing to startx with chromium

Tags: kiosk, startx

I am trying to launch a single application - chromium without the rest of the desktop. I am trying this command (in terminal mode):

`$ startx chromium-browser --`

It proceeds to start the X server, but then simply exits back to the command line. I have tried with and without the trailing `--`. If I execute just `startx`, the desktop starts up like normal.

I am running Raspian-Jessie 2017-04-10.

I cannot find any reason for `startx` to fail and the log in `~/.local/share/xorg/Xorg.0.log` doesn't show anything either.

Any ideas?